# Trying to fill up empty spaces using Flex box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image]

Is it possible to make this yellow square floats naturally to the empty grey square and so on?
Each flex-item represents a component they can use 50% or 100% of the container width, but i just have this information when im rendering it.

I was considering use only flexbox, but i dont know if it is possible.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 240px;
  background: grey;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.flex-item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
 
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item red"></div>
    <div class="flex-item blue"></div>
    <div class="flex-item yellow"></div>
    <div class="flex-item green"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not with `flexbox` but with `css-grid`: `grid-auto-flow: row dense;`

Comment: You can also use order ... to reorder elements in the flow, so the yellow boxe can be painted before the blue one is ;) https://jsfiddle.net/Lqzj0p2y/

Comment: @G-Cyrillus but you need to know how many elements you have and how much space they fill. Then you could mostlikely code them in that order in the first place.

Comment: @tacoshy yes, but he did not say he did not and that is only a comment ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CSS-Grid it is possible by using the [grid-auto-flow property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow): `grid-auto-flow: row dense;`

That will place items as dense as possible and automatically re-order them.

1. change `.flex-container { display: flex; }` to: change `.flex-container { display: grid; }` to use CSS-Grid
2. remove: `.flex-container { height: 240px; flex-wrap: wrap; align-content: flex-start; }` to remove unecessary flex-properties
3. change `.flex-item { width: 100px; }`to: `.flex-item { min-width: 100px; }` which allows the elements to be widerr then 100px.
4. change `.blue { width: 200px; }` to: `.blue { grid-column: span 2; }` to have that element twice the width.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: grid;
  width: 200px;
  background: grey;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
}

.flex-item {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
 
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item red"></div>
    <div class="flex-item blue"></div>
    <div class="flex-item yellow"></div>
    <div class="flex-item green"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do see there are some comments about this and @Tacoshy is correct that grid is a better solution. But - here is how you can do that using `order` with `flex` since the OP specified "using flexbox":

(I also changed the height of the gray `div` to 300 from 240 for obvious reasons.)

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: grey;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.flex-item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  order: 0;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  order: 2
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  order: 1;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  order: 3
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item red"></div>
    <div class="flex-item blue"></div>
    <div class="flex-item yellow"></div>
    <div class="flex-item green"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot use order ;/